# Sas/Sata raid controller with dedicated management interface?

Tags: raid, hardware

I am looking for an internal raid controller that has a dedicated Ethernet port for management. I would really like to have operating system independent management of the raid without having to drop to BIOS. For some reason I think I have seen these in the past but cant find any for the life of me now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest this might be cheating (since I gave you the answer offline after you asked this), but I'm claiming my points anyway ;-)

Check http://www.bestcovery.com/areca-arc-1280ml-raid-controller-card

> As with the 1680ix, the 1280ML also sports an Ethernet port for remote management of the RAID card through Areca's browser-based management GUI.

Comment: I was wrong - i still fail to see the point though ;)

Comment: Yeah looks like many of the areca cards have dedicated interfaces. Seems like the only manufacturer I can find that does it so far. Seems like the best way to have true operating system independent raid subsystem management.